# Replacing hard coded values with comma separated value from a column

Tags: sql, plsql

This code snippet is part of a procedure which executes some PL SQL statements based on the IF expression:

The procedure consists this IF statement:

**IF ( status IN ( 'A', 'B' ) ) THEN...**

There is a table, one of whose column contains the value 'A,B'

Instead of hardcoding the value, i want the IF statement to use it from the table column

Something like:

**IF ( status IN column_name ) THEN...**

Please provide a possible solution for this problem and let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: Study the SQL WHERE -clause: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)

Comment: More info? Yes what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
IF STATUS IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM SOME_TABLE) THEN
  DO_SOMETHING_USEFUL;
END IF;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming comma separated values in the COLUMN_VALUE column, something like:

IF ','||COLUMN_VALUE||',' LIKE '%,' || STATUS || ',%'